# How to determine via API that a Document was deleted in the web sender?

Tags: docusignapi

When I go to the Documents tab in the web sender there are no documents listed, but when I use the Java API to list envelopes:
EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.listStatusChanges(accountId, options);
I get documents when I don't expect any.  I then realized that all the documents listed via the API are "deleted" documents in the web GUI, but haven't been able to find how to determine via the API that these documents have been deleted - their status is "Completed".

So two questions come from this:
- Is there any way to empty the trash in the web GUI to permanently delete documents?
- Is there any way via the REST API to determine that an envelope has been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there any way to empty the trash in the web GUI to permanently delete documents?

You can move documents to the deleted folder. DocuSign will later empty that folder automatically in the background.

From [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-delete-documents)

> Deleted documents remain in your Deleted bin for only a short time (less than 24 hours), after which they are removed permanently and cannot be recovered.

Comment: That doesn't actually address what I asked.  If I delete a document and it stays in the deleted bin for up to 24 hours, when I'm accessing the envelope list via the API during those hours before it is deleted permanently I need to be able to tell that it has been marked as deleted (so I can ignore it).  As far as I can see right now there is no obvious way to tell it apart from any other envelope which has not been deleted.